# How to speed up a process

Tags: performance-tuning, timing

I am wondering how to speed up the following code: Currently it takes more than two sec to be processed.

```
Timing[For[i = 1;

list = {}, i <= 11111, i++, l = AppendTo[list, i/Pi]];
 Total@N@list]
```

I am new to Wolfram languages and it's the only thing I could come up with.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see in @MarcoB's answer the enormous speed up possible.

Even for your code, if you replace the `AppendTo` with a different structure, you can get orders of magnitude improvement.

Your code here - note that we don't need `l` for anything.

```
( For[i = 1; list = {}, i <= 11111, i++, AppendTo[list, i/Pi]];
Total@N@list ) //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.12476, 1.96501*10^7}

Slight modification results in factor of 100 speed up.

```
(For[i = 1; list = {}, i <= 11111, i++, list = {list, i/Pi}];
Total@N@Flatten@list) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0287278, 1.96501*10^7}

Answer (score 10):

```
Total@Range[11111]/Pi // N

(*Out: 1.96501*10^7 *)
```

---

In general:

- avoid `For` loops: see: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951)
- avoid `Append` / `AppendTo` because they generate a new list every time you add an element; instead, generate lists with `Table`, `Array`, `Range`, `Reap / Sow` instead;
- See also: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951)

---

Just for some timing context, and to compare `For` with `Do`:

```
n = 10^6; rpt = RepeatedTiming;

(For[i = 1; list = {}, i <= n, i++, list = {list, i}]; Total@N@Flatten[list];) // rpt
(For[i = 1; list = {}, i <= n, i++, list = {list, i}]; N@Total@Flatten[list];) // rpt

(list = {}; Do[list = {list, i}, {i, n}]; Total@N@Flatten[list];) // rpt
(list = {}; Do[list = {list, i}, {i, n}]; N@Total@Flatten[list];) // rpt

Total@N@Range[n]; // rpt
N@Total@Range[n]; // rpt

n (n + 1)/2.; // rpt



(* Out:

For loops: 1.35  s
           1.40  s

Do loops:  0.980 s
           0.887 s

Range:     0.01  s
           0.007 s

formula:   1 x 10^-6 s 

*)
```

Comment: Of course, you don't need to know the formula.  Mathematica will work it out for you in fraction of the time it took to do the `For` loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 11111;
Total@Range[11111]/Pi // N // RepeatedTiming
n (n + 1)/(2. Pi)// RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000034, 1.96501*10^7}
>
> {1.2*10^-6, 1.96501*10^7}

Comment: He. Good old Carl Friedrich to the rescue... :-) I'd go for `n (n + 1)/2. / Pi` then, to avoid `N` and squeeze the last few microseconds out